# Impute na using average on both sides in row

Tags: r, na

When I visualized my data, it had a series of periodicities in row. But Randomforest imputing and PCA imputing create outlier.

**Main problem** :

So i want to average on both sides in row. When the `NA` value of the nth column occurs, the average of `n-1` column and `n+1` column impute corresponding row.

Sub problem

1. But first column and last column doesn't have `n-1` or `n+1`, therefore i will take n+1 or n-1.(don't worry, deviation of row is very small.)
2. It occur na value in row continuosly. It also take `n-1` or `n+1`.

**EX:**

```
tr <- structure(list(A_1 = c(NA,2,3,4,5), A_2 =c(4,5,6,NA,8), A_3 = c(7,9,NA,10,11), 
                     A_4 = c(10,12,NA,13,NA), A_5 =c(12,NA,14,15,16), A_6 = c(13,15,15,16,17)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -5L),class = "data.frame")
> tr
  A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4 A_5 A_6
1  NA   4   7  10  12  13
2   2   5   9  12  NA  15
3   3   6  NA  NA  14  15
4   4  NA  10  13  15  16
5   5   8  11  NA  16  17
```

**Desired output**

```
> tr
      A_1 A_2 A_3   A_4   A_5  A_6
    1   4   4   7    10    12   13
    2   2   5   9    12  13.5   15
    3   3   6   6    14    14   15
    4   4   7  10    13    15   16
    5   5   8  11  13.5    16   17
```

Comment: Similar question: [Transform NA values based on first registration and nearest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130682/transform-na-values-based-on-first-registration-and-nearest-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way via `dplyr` is to convert to long format, take the `lag()` and `lead()` of your value column, compute the row means, replace NA and convert back to wide. i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tr %>% 
 pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
 mutate(n1 = lag(value), n2 = lead(value)) %>% 
 mutate(res = rowMeans(select(., c(n1, n2)), na.rm = TRUE), 
        value = replace(value, is.na(value), res[is.na(value)])) %>% 
 select(name, value) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% 
 unnest()
```

which gives,

```
    A_1   A_2   A_3   A_4   A_5   A_6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     4     7  10    12      13
2     2     5     9  12    13.5    15
3     3     6     6  14    14      15
4     4     7    10  13    15      16
5     5     8    11  13.5  16      17
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
# Define helper function
foo <- function(x) sapply(transpose(shift(x, -1:1)), mean, na.rm = TRUE)

setDT(tr)[, melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns("^A"))
          ][, value := fcoalesce(value, foo(value)), by = rowid(variable)
            ][, dcast(.SD, rowid(variable) ~ variable)
              ][, !"variable"]

   A_1 A_2 A_3  A_4  A_5 A_6
1:   4   4   7 10.0 12.0  13
2:   2   5   9 12.0 13.5  15
3:   3   6   6 14.0 14.0  15
4:   4   7  10 13.0 15.0  16
5:   5   8  11 13.5 16.0  17
```

Or avoid the melting/dcasting with `apply()` from base R:

```
tr[] <- t(apply(tr, 1, function(x) fcoalesce(x, foo(x))))

  A_1 A_2 A_3  A_4  A_5 A_6
1   4   4   7 10.0 12.0  13
2   2   5   9 12.0 13.5  15
3   3   6   6 14.0 14.0  15
4   4   7  10 13.0 15.0  16
5   5   8  11 13.5 16.0  17
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution:

```
t(apply(tr, 1, function(x){
  ifelse(!is.na(x), x,
         rowMeans(cbind(c(NA, x[-length(x)]), c(x[-1], NA)), na.rm = T))
}))

#      A_1 A_2 A_3  A_4  A_5 A_6
# [1,]   4   4   7 10.0 12.0  13
# [2,]   2   5   9 12.0 13.5  15
# [3,]   3   6   6 14.0 14.0  15
# [4,]   4   7  10 13.0 15.0  16
# [5,]   5   8  11 13.5 16.0  17
```