# Complete NA value horizontally in a dataframe, at each cell value change via Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

My dataframe looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_input <- data.frame(
                   variant_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                       August = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                    September = c(0.05, NA, 0.04, 0.09, NA, NA),
                      October = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.25, 0.09),
                     November = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.12, NA, NA),
                     December = c(NA, 0.04, NA, 0.12, 0.09, NA),
                      January = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.12, NA, 0.09),
                     February = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
                )

> df_input
  variant_id August September October November December January February
1          1     NA      0.05    0.05       NA       NA      NA       NA
2          2     NA        NA    0.04       NA     0.04      NA       NA
3          3     NA      0.04    0.04       NA       NA      NA       NA
4          4     NA      0.09    0.12     0.12     0.12    0.12       NA
5          5     NA        NA    0.25       NA     0.09      NA       NA
6          6     NA        NA    0.09       NA       NA    0.09       NA
```

I want to complete the `NA` value horizontally following these rules:

For each row:

1. Find the first non-`NA` value
2. Copy this value on the subsequent `NA` value horizontally
3. At the first non-`NA` value, switch the value to copy

For example, let's take `variant_id` = `2`.

1. The first non-`NA` value is `0.04` in the column `October`
2. Copy `0.04` in the column `November`.
3. Keep the value in the column `December` `0.04`
4. Copy `0.04` in the columns `January` and `Februrary`

For `variant_id` = `5`

1. The first non-`NA` value is `0.25` in the column `October`
2. Copy `0.25` in the column `November`
3. Then the value switch to `0.09` in December.
4. Copy `0.09` in the columns `January` and `February`

The output should be:

```
df_output <- data.frame(
                variant_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                    August = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 September = c(0.05, NA, 0.04, 0.09, NA, NA),
                   October = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.25, 0.09),
                  November = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.25, 0.09),
                  December = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.09, 0.09),
                   January = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.09, 0.09),
                  February = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.09, 0.09)
             )

> df_output
  variant_id August September October November December January February
1          1      0      0.05    0.05     0.05     0.05    0.05     0.05
2          2     NA        NA    0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
3          3     NA      0.04    0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
4          4     NA      0.09    0.12     0.12     0.12    0.12     0.12
5          5     NA        NA    0.25     0.25     0.09    0.09     0.09
6          6     NA        NA    0.09     0.09     0.09    0.09     0.09
```

I assume I could use the functions `fill` or `complete` in `dplyr` but I don't know how to apply the function "horizontally".

Comment: Related post: [Transform NA values based on first registration and nearest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130682/transform-na-values-based-on-first-registration-and-nearest-values)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `dplyr` answer but it is the shortest I can imagine.

```
df_input[-1] <- t(apply(df_input[-1], 1, zoo::na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
df_input
#  variant_id August September October November December January February
#1          1      0      0.05    0.05     0.05     0.05    0.05     0.05
#2          2     NA        NA    0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
#3          3     NA      0.04    0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
#4          4     NA      0.09    0.12     0.12     0.12    0.12     0.12
#5          5     NA        NA    0.25     0.25     0.09    0.09     0.09
#6          6     NA        NA    0.09     0.09     0.09    0.09     0.09
```

Comment: Can use na.locf0 which defaults to na.rm = FALSE.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks, I had read only up to `na.locf`, never `na.locf0` that `Implicitly, it uses na.rm=FALSE.`

Comment: na.locf0 was added in zoo 1.8.0 three years ago so if you don't have it suggest you get a more recent version of the package (and actually it was there prior to that but not exported).

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Yes, I do, my version is 1.8.8. I hadn't noticed `na.locf0`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would require to first make the data in long format with `pivot_longer`, `fill` the NAs downwards grouping by `variant_id`, and then re-pivot the dataset in a wide format with `pivot_wider`.

```
df_input %>% 
  pivot_longer(August:February) %>% 
  group_by(variant_id) %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = "down") %>% 
  pivot_wider(variant_id)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   variant_id [6]
#   variant_id August September October November December January February
#        <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1          1      0      0.05    0.05     0.05     0.05    0.05     0.05
# 2          2     NA     NA       0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
# 3          3     NA      0.04    0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
# 4          4     NA      0.09    0.12     0.12     0.12    0.12     0.12
# 5          5     NA     NA       0.25     0.25     0.09    0.09     0.09
# 6          6     NA     NA       0.09     0.09     0.09    0.09     0.09
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df_input <- data.frame(
  variant_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  August = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  September = c(0.05, NA, 0.04, 0.09, NA, NA),
  October = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.12, 0.25, 0.09),
  November = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.12, NA, NA),
  December = c(NA, 0.04, NA, 0.12, 0.09, NA),
  January = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.12, NA, 0.09),
  February = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

List <- split(df_input,df_input$variant_id)

modify <- function(x)
{
  vec<-as.vector(x[,-1])
  vec2 <- na.locf(t(vec),na.rm = F)
  vec3 <- as.vector(t(vec2))
  names(vec3)<-names(vec)
  vec4 <- c(x$variant_id,vec3)
  return(vec4)
}

List2 <- lapply(List,modify)

DFFinal <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,List2))

V1 August September October November December January February
1  1      0      0.05    0.05     0.05     0.05    0.05     0.05
2  2     NA        NA    0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
3  3     NA      0.04    0.04     0.04     0.04    0.04     0.04
4  4     NA      0.09    0.12     0.12     0.12    0.12     0.12
5  5     NA        NA    0.25     0.25     0.09    0.09     0.09
6  6     NA        NA    0.09     0.09     0.09    0.09     0.09
```